# how can i refer to a string array inside and array list

Tags: java, arrays, string, get, arraylist

i have an array list that is holding two string arrays.. one dedicated to usernames and another to passwords

```
    ArrayList<Person> popul = new ArrayList<Person>();
    String[] u = {"Herp","Derp","LOL"};
    String[] p = {"hello123", "qwerty42", "iliketurtles"};
```

in another class inside the main method i am trying to get the passwords from the popul arrayList to turn into hash.. i have set up a loop to get each password but I do not know how to get only from the password string array and not the username...

```
for(int x = 0; x < popul.size(); x++){
  popul.get(x);
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: I do not see the connection between `popul`, `people`, `u` and `p`. Please clarify.

Comment: please provide a more clear code sample of what you are doing.  I do not see how you are using the arrays u or p and there is no declaration of people at all.

Comment: sorry, completely screwed up writing the code, mixed some things up.. apologize for the lack of attention

Answer (score 0):

Confusing code, I am assuming you have an arraylist holding 2 String arrays u and p and you want to traverse the passwords array. If that is correct, and if u added u first and p later, your password array can be retrieved by

```
popul.get(1);
```

So to traverse the passwords you should be doing

```
for(String password: popul.get(1))
{
 System.out.println(password);
}
```